# Internet Explorer overflow in page-content results in double scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer, overflow

I'm using a bootstrap design with the following html (shortened)

```
<body>
    <div class="page-container">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="page-content-wrap">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12" id="div1">
                        <!-- some table -->
                    </div>
                </div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The table is dynamically loaded with a ajax call, which results in a overflow. (there is other static stuff as well)
The Problem in IE10 is that both the body and page-content produce a scrollbar, which are on top of each other (at least in my understanding) and scrolling is very awkward. If I remove 'overflow: auto' from page-content the scrolling is fine but the page-content does not adapt to the overflow. I played around with 'ms-overflow-style' and different configurations of 'overflow' but I can't get it to work.

The relevant CSS looks like this:

```
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.body-full-height {
  height: 100%;
}
.body-full-height body {
  height: 100%;
}
.page-container {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.page-container .page-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to:

```
.page-container .page-content {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  zoom: 1;
  overflow: null;
}
```

## It might prevent the display error

Comment: That fixes the scrollbar problem but the overflow is not handled, see this picture: http://imgur.com/ZjwauPH

Comment: Try switching null to hidden, it might still render.

Comment: Nope, it does not render anymore.